# fingerprint Touch ID installation error when runs in React native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, fingerprint

I followed this documentation [link](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-touch-id) and when I installed this

`npm i --save react-native-touch-id` and `react-native link react-native-touch-id`

when I run **npx react-native run-android** I get this error

[image]

It would be great if anybody help me for this, thank you so much in advance!.

**Error**

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android 
development environment set up: 
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug - 
PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-touch-id'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native- 
touch-id:classpath'.
> Could not download kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.20.jar 
(org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.20)
  > Could not get resource 
'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib- 
jdk8/1.3.20/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.20.jar'.
     > Could not GET 
'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib- 
jdk8/1.3.20/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.20.jar'.
        > peer not authenticated
 > Could not download jimfs-1.1.jar (com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1)
  > Could not get resource 
 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/jimfs/jimfs/1.1/jimfs-1.1.jar'.
     > Could not HEAD 
 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/jimfs/jimfs/1.1/jimfs-1.1.jar'.
        > peer not authenticated
 > Could not download httpmime-4.5.2.jar 
 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2)
  > Could not get resource`https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.2/httpmime-4.5.2.jar.`
> peer not authenticated
```

Answer (score 0):

@Shainnah Jane,

Hi Shainnah Jane, I had the same issue i think cause of the compileSdkVersion, as the library required version 31 for me and I was using 30. When i updated by compiledSdkVersion it worked for me.

React Natve: Go to you rootfolder -> android -> build.gradle

change the compileSdkVersion
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2cp0.png)